# How to listen to safari extension popup toolbar button event

Tags: swift, macos, safari, safari-extension

[image: Toobar item]

I am developing a safari app extension.
I have created a popup toolbar item that looks like this.
How can I get the value from textfield when tapped on the submit button.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I may b late but here you will find source code which shows you to add button event -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/developing_a_safari_web_extension

You will require `default_popup` in `manifest.json` like,

```
"background": {
        "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
    },

    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": [ "content.js" ],
        "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
    }],
    
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "images/toolbar-icon-16.png",
            "32": "images/toolbar-icon-32.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
```

and `popup.html` would contain reference for `popup.js`=>

```
<head>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="title">
    Sea Creator
    </div>
    <button id="share">Share on example.com!</button>
</body>
```

`popup.js` would be like,

```
function shareOnExample()
{
    // Use optional permissions to request access to www.example.com.
    browser.permissions.request({origins: ['https://www.example.com/']}, (granted) => {
        if (granted) {
            // Share Sea Creator's info to example.com.
        }
    });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.getElementById("share").addEventListener("click", shareOnExample);
});
```

Here you see, click event listener is added for share button.

For more info, you can also check this video -> https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10665/

Comment: Thank you so much, Paresh. I will try it using the above code.